# Which linear operators satisfy the product rule?

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations, real-numbers

Let the vector space of functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be called $\mathbb{F}$. What are the linear operators on $\mathbb{F}$ that satisfy the product rule? It easily follows from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4588139/is-there-a-simple-way-to-characterize-the-smooth-functions-without-using-the-der) that such a linear operator must be the derivative operator if $T(x) = 1$.

Comment: The word you're looking for is derivations. Unless I'm missing something, the link you provided describes a proper subset of those derivations which satisfy the chain rule.

Comment: I was asking about the product rule, and I wanted something for all functions, not just smooth functions.

Comment: I was replying to "If we restrict ourselves to smooth functions, then it easily follows from this question that such a linear operator must be a multiple of the derivative operator."

Comment: It follows that such a linear operator $T$ must be a multiple of the derivative operator... only if $T(x)$ is a constant function. (Here $x$ is the identity function.) What if $T(x)$ is not constant?

Comment: Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4588886/interesting-properties-of-derivative-spaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $D$ be a derivation on $\mathbb F$ (a derivation is simply [a linear operator on an algebra which satisfies the product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra))). For $S \subseteq \mathbb R$, let $\mathcal I_S$ denote the indicator function of $S$, and observe that $\mathcal I_S^2 = \mathcal I_S$.

So $D(\mathcal I_S) = D(\mathcal I_S^2) = 2\mathcal I_S D(\mathcal I_S)$ by the product rule. It readily follows that $D(\mathcal I_S)$ vanishes on both $\mathbb R \setminus S$ and on $S$, therefore $D(\mathcal I_S)=0$. Since $D$ is linear, it follows that all functions with finite range are in the kernel of $D$.

Now consider $\mathcal I_S g$ for arbitrary $g \in \mathbb F$. The product rule tells you $D(\mathcal I_S g) = \mathcal I_S D(g)$. But consider the case when $g$ vanishes outside of $S$, and therefore $g = \mathcal I_S g$. Then you get $D(g) = \mathcal I_S D(g)$, i.e., $D(g)$ vanishes everywhere $g$ vanishes.

Of course, functions don't vanish everywhere, but they take *some* value everywhere. Let $c \in g(\mathbb R)$ be any member of the range of $g$, and let $T$ be the fiber above $c$. By linearity, we have $D(g) = D(g)-0 = D(g)-D(c) = D(g-c)$ vanishes on $T$. By varying $c$, we can conclude that $D(g)$ vanishes everywhere. So $D$ is the zero operator.